# Can I remove some element from a Range in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a ClosedRange from 1 to 10, I wanted to know can we remove some element of it? like removing 5 and 7 from that closedRange then we should have: 1 2 3 4 6 8 9 10 instead of having 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
let closedRange: ClosedRange<Int> = 1...10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ends up being an array of type `[ClosedRange<Int>.Element]` because once you remove elements, it's not a range any more (since by definition it doesn't include all the elements between the bounds).

From the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange):

> An interval from a lower bound up to, and including, an upper bound.

```
let closedRange: ClosedRange<Int> = 1...10
let closedRangeArrayWithElementsMissing = closedRange.filter { $0 != 5 && $0 != 7 }
// = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: So then I think we can not merge them either, right? we can just define and use. I mean as Range, but as array yes

Comment: What does "merge them" mean?

Comment: like: 1..5 merge 6..10 => 1..10

Comment: Ah -- okay, different issue. You could do `let result = closedRange.lowerBound...closedRange2.upperBound`, but keep in mind that it doesn't check for "missing" numbers -- it just makes a range from the lower bound of the first one to the upper bound of the second one.

Comment: thanks for your info and help, I like using range they are much faster than array but we cannot do things that we can do with array or Set or dic, like removing some elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer states, no. `symmetricDifference` is good for this.

```swift
([5, 7] as Set).symmetricDifference(1...10)
```